# Integration by parts for measures

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $\mu_t$ be the law of a random process $X_t$. Let $\nu$ and $\nu_t$ be arbitrary measures in $\Omega$ with the sole restriction that $\mu_t$ be absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\nu_t$, and $\nu_t$ be absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\nu$.

Then (according to a paper I'm reading)
$$\int \partial_t \log \left(\frac{\nu_t(x)}{\nu(x)} \right) d\nu_t = \int \frac{\mu_t(x)}{\nu_t(x)} \partial_t \left(\frac{\nu_t(x)}{\nu(x)} \right)d\nu = - \int \partial_t \left(\frac{\mu_t(x)}{\nu_t(x)}\right) d \nu_t.$$

The second inequality looks like an integration by parts, but I don't know what it means to take "$dv$" = $\partial_t \left(\frac{\nu_t(x)}{\nu(x)} \right)d\nu $ where the "$dv$" derivative is with respect to a different variable (t) than the integral is taken over (\nu) -- usually "dv" is something like $\frac{d}{dx}v(x) dx$. And I don't understand the first inequality at all.

I'm also not sure what the notation $\frac{\nu_t(x)}{\nu(x)}$ is when we're talking about measures - I know it's not simply a fraction but something like a Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Comment: the first equality does not make sense to me, I don't think it can hold for any $\mu$ and $\nu$ as you've described. please link the paper

Comment: @Ilya it's remark 3.2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.03418.pdf

Comment: It’s not clear what is the “term” they refer to there, maybe the whole product under the integral sign? Check where it is used in the proof. The first part can’t be true as one side contains $\mu$ whereas the other does not depend on it at all

Comment: Also, some definitions there are given for discrete probability spaces, and are rather misleading.  I would not be surprised if there are mistakes and typos in this paper.

Comment: I think $\int \partial_t \log \psi_t \, d\nu_t$ in the remark is a typo and should be $\int g_t \partial_t \log \psi_t \, d\nu_t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned, I would not trust every single part of the paper you are referring to, as there a probably some unchecked typos or even mistakes: since it is on arXiv, it may be not peer reviewed yet. But some things I can help you with clarifying. I think it is more formally correct to write $g_t(x) = \frac{\mathrm d\mu_t}{\mathrm d\nu_t}(x)$ rather that $\frac{\mu_t(x)}{\nu_t(x)}$ since here $\nu_t(x)$ is not even defined, as a measure it is a function of sets, not of points.

One thing that makes is easier to work with RN derivatives is the following: if $\mu, \nu \ll \lambda$ then
$$
\frac{\mathrm d\mu}{\mathrm d\nu} = \frac{\mathrm d\mu}{\mathrm d\lambda}/\frac{\mathrm d\nu}{\mathrm d\lambda}. \tag{1}
$$
Note that it makes total sense symbolically, but still on the left hand side of $(1)$ you have a RN derivative, not any true ratio, whereas on the right hand side you have indeed a usual ratio of (density) functions. You can always find this $\lambda$, e.g. take $\lambda = \frac12(\mu + \nu)$. For example, it means that
$$
\frac \partial {\partial t}\left(\log\frac{\mathrm d\nu_t}{\mathrm d\nu}\right) = \frac \partial {\partial t}\left(\log\left(\frac{\mathrm d\nu_t}{\mathrm d\lambda}/\frac{\mathrm d\nu}{\mathrm d\lambda}\right)\right) = \frac \partial {\partial t}\left(\log\frac{\mathrm d\nu_t}{\mathrm d\lambda} - \log\frac{\mathrm d\nu}{\mathrm d\lambda}\right) = \frac{\frac\partial{\partial t}\frac{\mathrm d\nu_t}{\mathrm d\lambda}}{\frac{\mathrm d\nu_t}{\mathrm d\lambda}} = \left(\frac\partial{\partial t}\frac{\mathrm d\nu_t}{\mathrm d\lambda}\right)\frac{\mathrm d\lambda}{\mathrm d\nu_t}.
$$
Here we used two facts. First of all, $\lambda$ should be $\lambda_t$ in general, but since all $\nu_t$ are said to be dominated by the same measure, we were able to pick a single $t$-independent dominating measure $\lambda$. Moreover,
$$
\frac1{\frac{\mathrm d\nu_t}{\mathrm d\lambda}}  = {\frac{\mathrm d\lambda}{\mathrm d\nu_t}}.
$$
Some of these equalities are guaranteed to hold only a.s. but again, everything here is dominated by $\nu$, so that's not a problem. As a result, for every function $f(x)$ it holds that
\begin{align}
\int_X f(x)\frac \partial {\partial t}\left(\log\frac{\mathrm d\nu_t}{\mathrm d\nu}(x)\right)\nu_t(\mathrm dx) &= \int_Xf(x)\left(\frac\partial{\partial t}\frac{\mathrm d\nu_t}{\mathrm d\lambda}(x)\right)\frac{\mathrm d\lambda}{\mathrm d\nu_t}(x)\nu_t(\mathrm dx)
\\
&=\int_X f(x)\left(\frac\partial{\partial t}\frac{\mathrm d\nu_t}{\mathrm d\lambda}(x)\right)\lambda(\mathrm dx)
\\
&= \frac\partial{\partial t}\left(\int_X f(x)\frac{\mathrm d\nu_t}{\mathrm d\lambda}(x)\lambda(\mathrm dx)\right)
\\
&= \frac\partial{\partial t}\left(\int_X f(x)\nu_t(\mathrm dx)\right).
\end{align}

Note also that working with this you have to be accurate in something of the kind $b_t(x)\frac\partial{\partial t}a_t(x)$ which is
$$
b_t(x)\left.\left(\frac\partial{\partial s}a_s(x)\right)\right|_{s = t}
$$
cause otherwise you may get confused. I hope I didn't.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks a lot! I'm not well-acquainted with RN derivatives - is it generally true that $\int f(x) \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x) d\mu(x) = \int f(x) d\nu(x)$? (probably requiring that $\mu, \nu$ have the same support?)

Comment: @900edges yes, it's pretty much an alternative definition. If you take $f$ to be indicator function, you get a definition. Conversely, use linearity of integral and some convergence of simple functions to measurable ones. For details check out Folland's Real Analysis Section 3.2

Comment: ah yeah, got it. Thanks again.

Comment: To clarify, the first equality in my question doesn't make sense, right? I still don't know what that's supposed to say.

Comment: @900edges to me it does not, yes.